# replace a String with XSLT

Tags: xslt, wsdl

I have a wsdl (that I get from a Web Service) where I have to replace the current address String to something else , The Idea was to use XSLT to do that. There is just one problem , I have never done anything with XSLT so i have no idea how to do that. I have found an simple example of how to do that but I dot get how do i Get the old string out of the wsdl so I can replace it.

Here is the Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:inm="http://www.inmagic.com/webpublisher/query" version='1.0'>
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="text()"></xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>

    <xsl:for-each select="testObj">
      'Notes or subject' <xsl:call-template name="rem-html"><xsl:with-param name="text" select="SBS_ABSTRACT"/></xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="rem-html">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
<xsl:variable name="newtext" select="translate($text,'a','b')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

UPDATE :

this is what i have now :

```
<soap:address location="http://localhost:4434/miniwebservice"/>
```

this is what i want to get :

```
<soap:address location="http://localhost:4433/miniwebservice"/>
```

I just replaced the number of the Port from 4434 to 4433

Comment: Post us the example of input XML document and output you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="soap:address/@location">
    <xsl:attribute name="location">
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="haystack" select="current()"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="search">:4434/</xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="replace">:4433/</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that there are no built-in string replace function in XSLT, you'll need to take it somewhere else (e.g. http://symphony-cms.com/download/xslt-utilities/view/26418/ was used when writing this stylesheet).

Comment: I have just tried id out , replaced the "Example" comment with your suggestion but if i try to run it i get an exception : Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.

Comment: I have replaced match="soap:address/@location" with some random text and it compiled , did not replace the text but at least it compiled

Comment: You should declare a `soap` namespace in your `<xsl:stylesheet>` header; otherwise, you won't be able to refer to nodes/attributes in `soap` namespace. Just copy `xmlns:soap` attribute with its value from your source file root node to the `<xsl:stylesheet>`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that with XSLT 2.0 you have an easier way to proceed using regular expressions :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:soap="..."
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:param name="newPort">4433</xsl:param>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="soap:address/@location">
        <xsl:attribute name="location">
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,
                '^(http://[^/]*:)[0-9]{4}/',
                concat('$1',$newPort,'/'))"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To make it work, you just have to change the namespace URI in `xmlns:soap="..."` to the soap namespace uri (i'm not sure of it) and use an XSLT 2.0 processor (e.g. : saxon).